# Cutting a video with FFmpeg produces audio-only output

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I have to extract some small clips with FFmpeg but the movie produced has no video but only audio even if it is correctly an mp4 file.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -i ORIGINAL.mp4 -ss 5.263 -t 2.085 -y -avoid_negative_ts 1 -c copy OUTPUT.mp4
```

There was no output error from the console.

Here is the image of the files:
[image: screenshot]

The generated mp4 file has only audio and no video.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Video can only be spliced at keyframes. If there is no keyframe at `-t 2.085`, this operation can not be completed. You must transcode the video to covert the frame at `-t 2.085` into a keyframe. e.g.

`ffmpeg -i ORIGINAL.mp4 -ss 5.263 -t 2.085 -y -avoid_negative_ts 1 -acodec copy OUTPUT.mp4`

Comment: I would have preferred not to re-encode the video so as not to lose quality, thanks

Comment: Then the output will contain no decodable frames. Its one of the other, You can have both.